# JSON decode from object to string, and encode it back

Tags: json, scala, circe

I am trying to decode a JSON string to case class and also transform one of the field from Object to *JSON String*.

Currently, I have only finished the decoding part, but don't know how to implement the encoding part.

Here is my code:

```
case class Foo(objStr: String)
implicit val encoder: Encoder[Foo] = deriveEncoder[Foo]
implicit val decoder: Decoder[Foo] = deriveDecoder[Foo].prepare { cursor =>
  cursor.withFocus { json =>
    json.mapObject { o =>
      o.add("objStr", o("objStr").map(_.noSpaces.asJson).getOrElse(Json.Null))
    }
  }
}
val json =
  """{
    |  "objStr": {
    |     "0": 1,
    |     "1": 3.4,
    |     "2": "abc"
    |  }
    |}""".stripMargin

val foo = io.circe.parser.decode[Foo](json).right.get

println(foo)
// output `{"0":1,"1":3.4,"2":"abc"}` as expected

println(foo.asJson.noSpaces)
// output `{"objStr":"{\"0\":1,\"1\":3.4,\"2\":\"abc\"}"}`
// but I expect `{"objStr":{"0":1,"1":3.4,"2":"abc"}}`
```

Please help me to finish the encoding part.
Thank you.

**Updated:**

Found a workable solution:

```
implicit val encoder: Encoder[Foo] = deriveEncoder[Foo].mapJson { json =>
  json.mapObject { o =>
    o.add("objStr", o("objStr").flatMap(_.asString).flatMap(parse(_).toOption).getOrElse(Json.Null))
  }
}
```

Comment: You need a custom `Encoder` that parses the `String` again. However, I would say that it would be much easier if you just use `final case class Foo(obj: JsonObject)` so you can just use the automatically derived `Codec` and then you can call `toString on it whenever you need it.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I used to store the field in `Map[String, Any]`, but now the serialization framework used here only support primitive types and I can't think of another way to overcome.

Comment: If you need a `Map[String, Any]` you are writing **Python** not **Scala**, also **circe** supports much more than just primitives, check the docs. You can use proper case classes to model the data or you can stay with a `JsonObject` as I proposes as a type-safe alternative to `Map[String, Any]`

Comment: Sorry to didn't make it clear. I am developing a data pipeline by Flink. I use "the case class" as events and these events will be serialize by Flink and only support primitive types.

Comment: So you need to pass a `Map[String, Any]` to **Flink**? _(I am surprised **Flink** doesn't support something more typesafe)_ - But, not sure what you would do with a plain `String` then? You would re-parse the `String` at the other side too? - Anyways, it seems you already fixed your problem so good luck with that :)

Comment: Flink supports nested class, so we usually store map-like object in another case class.
The problem here is one of the column (`objStr`) store arbitrary data from users, there is no fixed schema for this column.